# Preseed Disk partition - Use existing partition with out create new partition - Patman ubuntu ISO

Tags: 18.04, partitioning, iso, preseed, isolinux

I have working on the Ubuntu upgrade from 14 to 18.04 ISO. So in my system already having two partitions:

```
/dev/sda1  Ext4   /
/dev/sda5  swap
```

I want to be use **existing partition (sda1) to install the latest OS 18** without format (format: no, keep existing data) and assign this as mount as root (mount: /)

I need to create the entries in to **preseed file as like below configuration** (manually select)

```
Use as : Ext4 jounaling filesystem
Format the partition: no, keep existing data
Mount point: /
Bootable flag: on
```

[image]

Please help on this.  i have spent too much time for this.

Note : i can achieve while doing manually select, but i have to done on the unattened ubuntu ISO part.

Thanks,

Ramesh

Comment: Please clarify.  Ubuntu desktop & server releases use the *yy.mm* format, where as *snap* based releases use the *yy* format.  Ubuntu Core 18 is the latest IoT release, however at other times you use 18.04 LTS (which uses *debs* as well as *snaps* where Ubuntu Core 18 relies on *snaps* only). Ubuntu 20.04 LTS is the latest *deb* based release. Are you talking about server? desktop? or given the *yy* format a snap based appliance/device? (thus Ubuntu Core)